# Automatic Spacing between multiple text objects

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting, spacing

**Hello, here is my issue:**

I am trying to set up a workbook where titles (h1, h2) and basic text (p) iterate a lot and vary in length.

Hence, between those text objects, I want to insert a "spacer" that keeps the same distance between two text objects and is pushed when a text object grows in length.

**This is what I try to achieve:**

*h1

SPACER

h2

SPACER

p

SPACER

h2

SPACER

p*

No matter how long a paragraph text object gets, the spacers always keep the same distance to the previous text object. This is necessary since various exercises in my workbook might have various paragraph-length.

How can I achieve this?

I am fairly new to indesign (mainly worked with illustrator so far). I've looked into text-chaining and text-frame-auto-resize but did not find the sought after set up.

Thank you

Comment: One more comment why I don't use simple text-chaining. I will link the text boxes to an excel sheet that feeds them with content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h1
SPACER
h2
SPACER
p
SPACER
h2
SPACER
p
```

If all this is part of the same text box, then use paragraph spacing with identical 'Space After' value for all styles (h1, h2, p) as mentioned by Julian. This should be the more efficint way.

The less efficient way, but I believe this is what you're trying to do here.. if you're planning to have separate text boxes for each paragraph, then you need to use text frame auto-size (height only), and set the same 'Bottom inset spacing' value for each text box. Then manually position all these boxes using the snap to object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thx ... this was (kind of) it. In an ideal solution, I could automatically order the textboxes so that one text box snaps to the previous one while each text box changes size automatically (this part is solved).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But is sounds like you need to use "Paragraph Spacing" for this.
You can set this in the paragraph panel, the top bar or double-click on the paragraph style.

Best way is through paragraph styles, as that allows to change all spacings together and makes sure they are all the same.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution for the problem you described. I have a resume set up as follows.

For each job I've held (4 in this example), there are 2 text frames: one with the job company and title, and a second with a description of the job duties.

- The first text frame (job company and title boxes) doesn't change
- The contents of the second frame, however, are frequently edited.
  These frames are set to auto-height (anchored at top), so that when
  the content is edited, the frames maintain the correct size.

I have used inset spacing in the text frames so that if I select all the boxes on the page, and Distribute Spacing: by a distance of 0, the whole thing aligns the way I want it.

[image: screenshot of well-aligned document]

The problem occurs when I shorten or lengthen one of the job descriptions. The text frame automatically adjusts its height. But the spacing does not update, so lengthened text frames overlap and shortened ones leave space.

[image: faulty formatting]

I could manually reselect all objects and click Distribute Spacing: again. **But it would really surprise me if there is no way to do this automatically.** It seems the feature would be important for other use cases.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/114308)